# android out of memory issue in page curl effect

Tags: android, 2d, out-of-memory, page-curl

in my app i am trying to show page curl effect using 100 images as explained in the following github link - [here](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl/blob/master/src/com/mystictreegames/pagecurl/AndroidPageCurlActivity.java)

In the sample code they are using only two images but in my app i am using around 90 images. This causes the app to get crashed, saying the following issue in logcat

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(603): Out of memory on a 5529616-byte allocation.
```

When i tried with 7 images it was working good. When i try to increase more than 7, it gets crashed. All my images are in drawable folder.

In that github code the images from drawable are taken as follows

```
mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page9));
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page10));
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page11));
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page12));
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page13));
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page14));
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.page15));
```

how to resolve this issue and load all the images, any better suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lazy loading mechanism. Do not load all bitmaps into memory at once, keep there id's in an `ArrayList`, and load them as you need them, and after using them, unload the bitmap, so that memory can be released.

Answer (score 0):

You must realize that the heap per application is quite limited in Android, so you can't use as much memory as on a desktop PC. So here are the solutions you might want to use:

1. Use smaller size images.
2. Optimize your application behavior, means you should not load any `Bitmaps` that aren't used at a moment and recycle them properly as soon as they become needless.
3. Limit the number of `Bitmaps`, which already works for you.

Hope you'll implement one of these to make your application work better.